# text in wrong place

Tags: html, css

so I have this problem and I tried so many things and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
I'm putting image between two texts.

but for some reason the way the text are shown is opposite from what i want.

I want the list to be in right side, and text in left.
in the css I write float left\right in each section but it does the opposite.
what am I missing?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

img {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: initial;
}

p {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

ol {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ol dir="rtl">
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>

  </ol>
  <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/">
    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYTRiNDQwYzAtMzVlZS00NTI5LWJjYjUtMzkwNTUzMWMxZTllXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDIzMzcwNjc@._V1_.jpg" alt="Game of Thrones" />
  </a>
  <p>
    <h2>
      some text just to see if this works.
    </h2>
  </p>
</div>
```

[image: photo of the problem]

Comment: There are several things: You do not need `float`. You have a `flex` parent. That's what flex is for. Why not change the order of the markup instead?

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand what you want to achieve, but if you put the list as the last item in your code it will be displayed correctly.

Mixing flex and float doesn't seem like a right way to do it. What you may be looking for is a: 
`justify-content: space-between;`
in your container class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a left-to-right layout, the first HTML element will appear on the far left, the second to its right, etc. Since you do have a left-to-right layout, the `ol` will be placed on the left, the `img` in the middle, and the `p` on the right. To reverse order, you should simply reverse the order of the elements in the HTML, so that the `p` is first, then the `img`, and only then the `ol`.

```
 <div class="container"> 
    <p>
        <h2>
            some text just to see if this works.
        </h2>
    </p>
    <a href=" https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/">
        <img src="GAMEOFTHRONES.jpg" alt="Game of Thrones" />
    </a>
    <ol dir="rtl">
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Note that your code has many issues (which are not related to the question so I am not addressing them here). I would recommend you to post it at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: RTL is only for the <ol> as I see. For flex container items appear in the order as they are in the code. If you want to have them reversed, use `flex-direction: row-reverse`

Comment: @PiotrKątny - I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: i'm not downvoting (do you see any minus?) - i only think that "rtl" in the question refers to "Ordered List" (<ol>) tag only. The rest of your answer is fine - it is one of possible solutions.

Comment: @PiotrKątny - At a certain reputation, you can see how many downvotes you got. Someone downvoted the answer, but I didn't think it was you necessarily, so I did not tag you. :) Anyway, I did not refer to the "rtl" part in my answer. All I said is that in general, since the markup defaults to ltr, the `ol` will show to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to mix multiple layout methods together, and they're conflicting with one another.

If you want to use `float`, do not put `flex` on the container. Header elements are `display:block` so you'd need to override its layout as well so it doesn't take full screen width (in this example I removed the unnecessary `<p>` and floated the `<h2>` instead.) Unfloated elements (the header) have to come after the floated ones if you want them to fall into the same row, so for this method we have to change the order of the HTML. (But note this will only work if there's enough horizontal space for all three elements; if not the un-floated element will wrap to the next row.)

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

h2 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

ol {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ol dir="rtl">
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
  </ol>
  <h2>
    some text just to see if this works.
  </h2>
  <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/">
    <img src="GAMEOFTHRONES.jpg" alt="Game of Thrones" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `flex`, do not use `float`. In this case you want the elements to go in right to left order; this can be done easily using `flex-direction` if you want to preserve the existing order of your HTML (which, given that you're using `rtl` text, seems likely to be what you want.)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ol dir="rtl">
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
  </ol>
  <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/">
    <img src="GAMEOFTHRONES.jpg" alt="Game of Thrones" />
  </a>
  <h2>
    some text just to see if this works.
  </h2>
</div>
```

In general, when writing CSS, the fewer rules you add the better. It's really easy to start piling new rules on top of the old ones and wind up with weird conflicts like you were running into; it's often easier to get where you want to go by *removing* rules instead of adding more.

Answer (score -1):

This will fix your problem:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

img {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: initial;
}

p {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px; /* fixed Spacing */
}

ol {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px; /* fixed Spacing */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- Flipped the p element and ol element to have them be on the sides that you wanted them to be on. -->
  <p>
    <h2>
      some text just to see if this works.
    </h2>
  </p>
  <a href="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/">
    <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYTRiNDQwYzAtMzVlZS00NTI5LWJjYjUtMzkwNTUzMWMxZTllXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDIzMzcwNjc@._V1_.jpg" alt="Game of Thrones" />
  </a>
  <ol dir="rtl">
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>

  </ol>
</div>
```